# onOptionsItemSelected isn't working

Tags: android, listview

I have here two problems. First is that nothing happens when i click on option item which i have set and in this case it is option for adding item which will take user to another activity, but nothing happens when i click on that. I have create one button which is calling the same activity and it is working. Also selecting item in listView isn't working and there should be one popup for delete item from listView and database, but there isn't. I would appricieate some help here and if anyone can suggest me how to create multiple choice selected in listView and counting how many items are checked something like [this](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/sJHyg2Pdx9s/maxresdefault.jpg)

**So here is my MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    // Declare variables
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private GroceryDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    Button addItem;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);

         // inflate the custom activity layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);

        frameLayout.addView(activityView);

        // Setting toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.shopping_cart_logo);

        // Setting database and adapter
        mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        // Locate ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Locate button and initialization
        addItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

            }
        });

        fillData();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData() {
        Cursor itemsCursor =  mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
        startManagingCursor(itemsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just title)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.price};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter items = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_row, itemsCursor, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(items);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, "Add Item");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createItem();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete Item");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteItem(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }
}
```

**Here is my AddActivity.java which should be called when users click on addItem from menu(which isn't working) and from button(which is working):**

```
    public class AddActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Long mRowId;
    private GroceryDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private EditText title_edit;
    private EditText price_edit;
    private Button saveButton;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity_layout);

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.shopping_cart_logo);


        // Locate the EditText in add_activity_layout.xml
        title_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        price_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceEdit);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;
        }

        populateFields();

        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
            }

        });

    }

    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor item = mDbHelper.fetchItem(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(item);
            title_edit.setText(item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            price_edit.setText(item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE)));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String title = title_edit.getText().toString();
        String price = price_edit.getText().toString();

        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createItem(title, price);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateItem(mRowId, title, price);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Here is my layout of MainActivity:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_item"
        style="@style/MyCustomButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/add_button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add_item"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider_row"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" >

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:padding="@dimen/relative_layout_padding" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Items"
            android:textColor="#474747"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_text"
            android:text="(2)"
            android:textColor="#474747"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Rs. 5700"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

*My code of BaseActivity:*

```
    package com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dusandimitrijevic.adapters.NavDrawerListAdapter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

     // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

     // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

     // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Shop
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Calendar
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Settings
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // About
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

     // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_back, R.anim.slide_out_back);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `addItem.setOnClickListener`, please use `listView.setOnItemClickListener`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }
});
```

For the menu item click,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == DELETE_ID) {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteItem(info.id);
            fillData();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have changed my onOptionItemSelected, but nothing happens when i click on listItem and also now happens when i click on add item from menu.